cannot assign instance of org.bson.BsonDocument to field org.apache.flink.connector.mongo..source.MongoSource.filter
I am new to Flink, and now I'm using flink 1.7 building a project with pyflink to query data from MongoDB and sink to Mysql. However, I keep getting error Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of org.bson.BsonDocument to field org.apache.flink.connector.mongo..source.MongoSource.filter of type org.bson.BsonDocument in instance of org.apache.flink.connector.mongodb.source.MongoSource. And, I guess that the error is from the flink-connector-mongodb module, but I'm not familiar with Java. Does anyone can help me solve this? Or what jar files did I miss?
The following is part of my code, and it includes the jars I used.
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
env.add_jars(
    "file:///opt/flink/lib/flink-sql-connector-mongodb-1.1.0-1.17.jar",
    "file:///opt/flink/lib/bson-5.1.2.jar",
    "file:///opt/flink/lib/mongodb-driver-sync-5.1.2.jar",
    "file:///opt/flink/lib/mongodb-driver-core-5.1.2.jar",
    "file:///opt/flink/lib/flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.2-1.17.jar",
    "file:///opt/flink/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar",
    "file:///opt/flink/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.13.jar",
    "file:///opt/flink/lib/slf4j-simple-2.0.13.jar",
)
env.add_classpaths(
    "file:///opt/flink/lib/bson-5.1.2.jar",
    "file:///opt/flink/lib/mongodb-driver-sync-5.1.2.jar",
    "file:///opt/flink/lib/mongodb-driver-core-5.1.2.jar",
)
t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
t_env.execute_sql(
    """
    CREATE TABLE source (
        ...
    ) with (
        'connector' = 'mongodb',
        ...
    )
)

t_env.execute_sql(
    """
    CREATE TABLE sink (
        ...
    ) with (
        'connector' = 'jdbc',
        ...
    )
)

table_result  = t_env.sql_query('...')
table_result.execute_insert("sink")
env.execute("MyMongoToMysql")

The full stack trace:
[jobmanager-io-thread-2] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.strategy.VertexwiseSchedulingStrategy - Using InputConsumableDecider org.apach
e.flink.runtime.scheduler.strategy.DefaultInputConsumableDecider for VertexwiseSchedulingStrategy.
[flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-20] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster - Starting execution of job 'insert-into_default_cat
alog.default_database.mysql_report_user_game_hourly' (822fedf047c8fde559f2c6118eee16f2) under job master id 00000000000000000000000000000000.
[flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-20] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster - Parallelism of JobVertex: Source: mongo_report_ord
er[1] -> Calc[2] -> HashAggregate[3] (cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2) is decided to be 1.
[flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-20] ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster - Unexpected error occurred when initializing Execu
tionJobVertex
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Cannot instantiate the coordinator for operator Source: mongo_report_order[1] -> Calc[2] -> HashAggregat
e[3]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.initialize(ExecutionJobVertex.java:229)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraph.initializeJobVertex(DefaultExecutionGraph.java:914)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.adaptivebatch.AdaptiveBatchScheduler.initializeVerticesIfPossible(AdaptiveBatchScheduler.java:288
)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.adaptivebatch.AdaptiveBatchScheduler.startSchedulingInternal(AdaptiveBatchScheduler.java:174)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.startScheduling(SchedulerBase.java:616)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.startScheduling(JobMaster.java:1044)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.startJobExecution(JobMaster.java:961)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.onStart(JobMaster.java:424)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.RpcEndpoint.internalCallOnStart(RpcEndpoint.java:198)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor$StoppedState.lambda$start$0(AkkaRpcActor.java:622)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor$StoppedState.start(AkkaRpcActor.java:621)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleControlMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:190)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
        at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:579)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:547)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of org.bson.BsonDocument to field org.apache.flink.connector.mongodb.source.Mon
goSource.filter of type org.bson.BsonDocument in instance of org.apache.flink.connector.mongodb.source.MongoSource
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:534)
        at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:522)
        at org.apache.flink.util.SerializedValue.deserializeValue(SerializedValue.java:67)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.OperatorCoordinatorHolder.create(OperatorCoordinatorHolder.java:471)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.createOperatorCoordinatorHolder(ExecutionJobVertex.java:286)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.initialize(ExecutionJobVertex.java:223)
        ... 32 more
[flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-20] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph - Job insert-into_default_catalog.default_
database.mysql_report_user_game_hourly (822fedf047c8fde559f2c6118eee16f2) switched from state CREATED to FAILING.
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Cannot instantiate the coordinator for operator Source: mongo_report_order[1] -> Calc[2] -> HashAggregat
e[3]
...


Can you provide full stack trace?

@jinzuchi Thanks for your reply. I have add the full stack trace.

I'm not 100% sure, but try this

change bson-5.1.2.jar to bson-4.7.2.jar
change mongodb-driver-core-5.1.2.jar to mongodb-driver-core-4.7.2.jar
change mongodb-driver-sync-5.1.2.jar to mongodb-driver-sync-4.7.2.jar


I have revised to 4.7.2, but I still get the same problem. Please check the full stack trace I've added, thanks.
